# Counting Techniques with Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I have a few problems and my attempts at solutions to them. I was wondering if someone could check over my work/help with those I might not understand?

1. how many telephone numbers have no 0 in the prefix (the first three numbers before the hyphen)?

To get the total possible 10-digit telephone numbers, it's simply 10^10, but that would be overcounting seeing that there are no zeros in the prefix. So, for the first three digits, it would be (edit) 9^3 * 10^7 for the remaining 7 digits= 7,290,000,000 telephone numbers. Does that look okay?

2. You bring a bag of 12 snacks to an animal shelter and realize that there are 18 animals there. You don't want to give more than 1 snack to any individual animal. How many ways are there of distributing snacks?

Would that just be 18 choose 12? =18,564?

3. How many 7 digit telephone numbers have an odd number of even numbers?

This one's kinda funky. If there's an odd number of even numbers, there would be 1,3,5, or 7 even numbers in the phone number. There are only 5 even numbers from 0-9 (including zero). So, I'm kind of confused on this one. Any ideas?

4. At the chocolate store, you decide to get a 20-chocolate box. There are creams (maple, vanilla, orange, lemon, chocolate) and caramels (milk chocolate, dark chocolate, walnut) and coated nuts (milk chocolate peanuts, dark chocolate peanuts, milk chocolate almonds, dark chocolate almonds, white chocolate almonds), as well as cherry cordials, white chocolate truffles, solid chocolate pieces (in both milk and dark chocolate), and yogurt&chocolate-coated pretzels. How many ways are there to fill the box?

This one has a load of information that makes it confusing. For the 20 chocolate box, we're dealing with:
5 types of cream, 
3 types of caramel, 
5 types of coated nuts, 
cherry cordials, 
white chocolate truffles, 
2 types of solid chocolate pieces, 
yogurt&chocolate coated pretzels.

I don't know where to begin. Should I add all the possibilities together? E.g. 5+3+5+1+1+2+1=18 Then it would be 20 choose 18= 190?

I appreciate any type of help/confirmation. Thanks!

Comment: You should think of a better title IMO.

Comment: $1$ and $2$ look good. $3$ has an intuitive solution: half of them. I think $4$ can be answered with 'stars and bars'

Comment: Problem 3 doesn't specify that you can only use each even number once in a given phone number. 222-2222 would be a phone number with 7 even numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to say that for #3, I guess I didn't word it properly!

Answer (score 2):

For problem $4$,
for each of the $18$ types, go on saying **yes** until you don't want any more, and then say **no** and move on to the next type.

Of course, you may say **no** straight away to any type if you don't want it, and you don't need to say **no** after the $18_{th}$ because there is no next type.

So there will be $20$ of **yes** and $17$ of **no** whichever way you choose, and the only decision you need to take is where to place the **no's** in the string of $37$ responses,

thus # of choices $=\dbinom{37}{17}$

For a more formal exposition of what is generally called "stars and bars" you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

Comment: "Stars and Bars" is one of our solving methods. For me, it's the most difficult to visualize, though, I have not thought of saying "yes" and "no" when approaching those types of problems. This helped a WHOLE lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're  welcome !